# Getting a seg fault when running sperform on Informix 12

Tags: informix

I'm pretty new to Informix and I'm trying to run a screen with `sperform`, but it's just seg faulting when I try to query.  So far I have:

- installed Ubuntu server 12 (64bit)
- installed the Dev suite and runtime 7.50
- installed the Informix engine 12.10
- verified it was all up and running; can connect with dbaccess
- created an example database & table and inserted a couple rows
- generated a form using `isql` from the table
- ran the generated form with `sperform`

As soon as I attempt to query with the form, I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and it exits.  Can anyone help me understand why?  Isn't this as basic as it gets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preliminary answer

Yes; that is as basic as it gets. No; it should not crash. There are essentially no circumstances under which that sequence should crash. You should probably file a bug report with IBM.

The only thing that might conceivably be an issue is that ISQL may have been built with an older version of the CSDK than the server installs and there may be an unexpected incompatibility. It should work, but occasionally flaws creep in. If you want to explore how to prove this possibility, say so. It is a little fiddly, but may get you up and running while the problem is resolved formally.

#### Extended answer

> YES! I'd love to try to fix this.

The first step, it seems to me, is to see whether ISQL (Informix SQL) runs correctly when installed on its own — rather than when mixed with the Informix server code.  It *should* work in both environments, but it is possible that the new server code has changed something that is causing the older tools code to break.

So, reinstall Informix SQL (and the other dev tools if you want, but you could save those until you've got a POC with just ISQL) into a new directory.  Let's suppose your server is installed in `/opt/informix`; you could install your tools in `/opt/isql` instead.  (No need to uninstall the tools from under `/opt/informix` yet.)

- Copy the server `sqlhosts` file (from `/opt/informix/etc/sqlhosts`) to the new `/opt/isql/etc/sqlhosts`.
- Change `INFORMIXDIR=/opt/isql`.
- Add the new value to the front of your path (`PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/bin:$PATH`).
- Worry about the setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` — you want to pick up libraries from under `/opt/isql/lib` in preference to those under `/opt/informix/lib`.
- Leave `INFORMIXSERVER` unchanged; you'll still be talking to the same database server.

You should now try to (re)generate the form file and run it.  With a small modicum of luck, it will work now.

> OK, that works! Don't know if that's a good thing or not, but we're going to try to get that change into production.

It gets you going; that's good.  It's also a relief to me that the fundamentals of the QA process for the tools release didn't break down.  The product works when run in the environment it was developed for.

It's a nuisance that a later release of the server changed something so that the older build of the tools no longer works with the newer server.  It is supposed to be OK.  However, running with separate INFORMIXDIR values for tools and server is not unheard of.  If the server was on a separate machine, the segregation would be inevitable — the tools would use a separate INFORMIXDIR from the one used by the server (ignoring NFS file systems, etc)

> Is it possible that there's some aspect to my steps that cause something to be overwritten?

No.  The classic 'Rule of TEN (Tools, Engine, Network)' — install tools before the server (before the network-enabled version of the server) more or less applies and is what you did.  The separate network-enabled version of the server ceased to be relevant about 20 years ago, but tools before engine (the 'Rule of TE' just doesn't cut it) is normally correct.

Since the workaround works, we need to look ahead a bit: what does it mean for you?

1. You have a solution that will work pro tem.
2. You will need to be careful with environment setting when you run programs.

   - Programs using the tools (Informix 4GL, Informix SQL) will be run with `INFORMIXDIR=/opt/isql` and consequential environment settings.
   - Programs installed by the server (DB-Export, DB-Import, ON-Stat, etc) will be run with `INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix` and consequential environment settings.
   - If you wish, you can set up scripts in `/opt/isql/bin` for the programs from `/opt/informix/bin` that you want developers or users to use.
   - The scripts in `/opt/isql/bin` will set the environment correctly for the server and then exec the server program.
   - The scripts in `/opt/informix/bin` will similarly set the environment correctly for the tools and then exec the tools program.
   - In each directory, assuming you're careful, you have a single script that actually sets the environment and runs the other program; the program names are simply (symbolic?) links to the master script.
   - You have two separate master scripts — one to set the server environment, one to set the tools environment.
3. You should report the problem to IBM (Informix) Technical Support.  You can outline what you've had to do to work around the problem.  The fact that you have a workaround will lower the urgency, but it is still a problem that should, ideally, be fixed.  (The world isn't ideal though, just in case you hadn't noticed; it may take time for the fix to be delivered.)

Comment: YES!  I'd love to try to fix this.  IBM is less than responsive.

Comment: I need to get to the office, but I can semi-legitimately claim it is 'work' when I get there. Short version: Re-install ISQL in a separate directory from the server (call it `/opt/isql`). Copy the server's sqlhosts file into `/opt/isql/etc/sqlhosts`. Set your PATH to pick up material from under `/opt/isql` before `/opt/informix` (or wherever your server is installed). Worry about LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Regenerate the form and run it using the new installation.  If that works, you're on your way and you have a reportable problem — you can tell 'em I said so. R&D will listen (not sure about support)

Comment: Ok, that works!  Don't know if that's a good thing or not, but we're going to try to get that change into production.  Is it possible that there's some aspect to my steps that cause something to be overwritten?